# SQL delete command deletes all entries in the table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have an application that is using SQL commands to interact with the database. One of the commands is the delete function, the syntax is correct and when I run it in the database works as it should be if I called it in my application it deletes all data.

This is the function that creates the query:

```cs
public void RemoveElement(string Language, long OrderID) {
   ConnectionString = CreateConnectionstring();

   string Query = @"DELETE FROM [dbo].[Orders] WHERE ([OrderID]=OrderID);";
   using (Command = new SqlCommand(Query, ConnectionString)){
       Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderID", OrderID);
       SqlExecution(Language, ConnectionString, Command);
   }
}
```

and this is the function that executes the query:

```cs
private void SqlExecution(string Language,SqlConnection ConnectionString, SqlCommand Command){
    try {
        ConnectionString.Open();
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Command.Dispose();
        // ...
    }
    //after this line they are message alerts to inform user about success or failure of the action
}
```

OrderID is PK, the query is executed as it should be (no errors or false data) but instead of deleting JUST the selected order it deletes everything (I used quickwatch and debugger and show's that only the selected order ID is passed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not a big fun of stringify commands, but I think you forget the `@`. Change `[OrderID] = OrderID` to `[OrderID] = @OrderID`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your query `[OrderID]=OrderID` means column OrderID equals column OrderID, so every row with not null OrderID is deleted. If you want ot pass parameter to query, you should put @ before it's name.
Try:

```cs
string Query = @"DELETE FROM [dbo].[Orders] WHERE [OrderID] = @OrderID;";
```

Comment: While your answer is correct, I'm hesitant to upvote such a short one. For extra credits please explain to the OP *what* they did wrong and *why*/ *how* your answer solves their problem

Comment: Thanks for quick response it solved the problem, although I am keen to learn why it deleted all the data instead of raising an error , if I am not mistaken the script would try to make  OrderID (numeric) equal to OrderID (string) so the sql should not raise event trying to compair diffrent type of types?

Comment: No in query you compare DB data with DB data. There is no data from `long OrderID`, because you don't use @Name or @Number. Parameter that you want include is ignored.

Comment: Equivalent versions of yours WERE part is: `[OrderID] = [OrderID]`, `OrderID = OrderID`, `"OrderID" = "OrderID"`, `[OrderID] = "OrderID"`, `OrderID = "OrderID"` or `[Orders].[OrderID] = [Orders].[OrderID]`

Comment: @PhilipValvis, TSQL performs type coercion. For example SELECT '1' + 1 or comparison SELECT '1' = 1

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to change your query to:

```
string Query = @"DELETE FROM [dbo].[Orders] WHERE ([OrderID]=@OrderID);";
```

PS: The reason why your query deletes all is because you delete all entries where the OrderID equals OrderID (so all) that syntax is useful when it is a foreign key, Example: OrderID = Customer.OrderID (where customer is another table)